# Inner product space $\langle v, x \rangle = \langle w, x \rangle \implies v = w$ on total set

Tags: inner-products

Let $M$ be a total subset of an inner product space $X$. Show that $\forall x \in M$:
$$
\langle v, x \rangle = \langle w, x \rangle \implies v = w
$$

My idea was to calculate
$$
\langle v, x \rangle - \langle w, x \rangle = \langle v - w, x \rangle = 0
$$
I know that no vector $a \in X$ can be perpendicular to all $x \in M$. So therefore $\exists x \in M$ such that $v-w \not\perp x$. So in order for this inner product to be $0$ $\forall x \in M$, one of the operands must be $0$. And $x$ can't be it since it is part of a total set.
$$
\implies v = w
$$
Is this proof correct? It seems too easy to be true

Comment: Your idea is correct but not your presentation. For example you should say 'no **non-zero** vector $a \in V$ can be orthogonal to $M$' instead of 'no vector $a \in V$ can be orthogonal to $M$'

Comment: I see, and then I could still conclude that $a = v - w = 0$

Comment: What is $V$ is your post?

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy oh, I'm sorry I got somethig mixed up there. All $V$s are supposed to be $X$s, I'm editing it

Comment: Okay, and what do you mean by 'I know that no vector ∈ can be perpendicular to all ∈' ? Surely it is the case for $a = 0$, and yes the property is true if $a$ is not the zero vector but if you already know this it suffices to take $a = v - w$ to conclude.

Comment: Since the span of $M$ is dense in $X$, every vector $a \in X$ can be represented by a linear combination of vectors $x_n \in M$. This means that $\langle a, x_n \rangle \ne 0$ for at least one $x_n$. A special example would be to think of $M$ as an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it is obvious, and the same holds true for general total sets

Comment: $a = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \alpha_k x_k, ~~\alpha_k \in \mathbb{R}, x_k \in M$. if $a \ne 0$ then at least one of the $\alpha_k$ is non-zero, so $a$ is not perpendicular to the respective $x_k$

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is a total subset, the closure of $\text{span} (M)$ is the whole space $X$. Now let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of $\text{span}(M)$ converging to $v-w$. For all $n$, we have

$$
\langle v-w, u_n \rangle = 0
$$

by linearity, and the inner product is of course continuous so letting $n$ goes to infinity we get

$$
\|v - w\|^2 = \langle v - w, v - w\rangle = 0
$$

and $v = w$.

Comment: How can $(u_n)$ be a sequence in $M$ that converges to $v - w$, when it isn't clear wether $v - w \in M$ or not?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\text{span}(M)$, not $M$, do you agree now?

Comment: I don't see why $\langle v - w, u_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n$. Also I fail to see why you could replace $x$ in the inner product with a random sequence. Shouldn't $u_n$ at least converge to $x$?

Comment: The statement $\langle v - w, x \rangle = 0$ holds for all $x \in M$ so if $y = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i$ with the $x_i$ in $M$, we have for all $i$, $\langle v - w, x_i \rangle = 0$ so  $\langle v - w, \alpha_i x_i \rangle = \alpha_i \langle v - w, x_i \rangle = 0$ and summing these equalities on $i$ and using bilinearity of the inner product we get $\langle v - w, y \rangle = 0$.

Comment: If you now specify that $y = v - w$ then I'm happy with this proof

Comment: Since $v - w$ is not necessarily in $\text{span} (M)$ we cannot do that, but since the closure of $\text{span} (M)$ is $X$, $v - w$ is in the closure of $\text{span} (M)$ so we can take a sequence $(y_n)$ of vectors of $\text{span}(M)$ converging to $v-w$. For each of those vectors, the result in my last comment holds, so by continuity of the inner product it still holds for the limit of $(y_n)$, i.e. for $v-w$. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Observing that the equality $\langle v, x \rangle - \langle w, x \rangle = \langle v - w, x \rangle = 0$ holds for all $x\in M$, we deduce that $v-w$ belongs to the orthogonal complement $M^\perp$. Given that $M$ is a total subset, it follows that the closure of the span of $M$, denoted as $\overline{\text{span}(M)}$, equals $X$. This, in turn, implies that the orthogonal complement $M^\perp$ consists solely of the zero vector, i.e., $M^\perp=\{0\}$. Consequently, the fact that $v-w\in\{0\}$ leads us to the conclusion that $v$ equals $w$.